# Change Meta Tag for different pages

Tags: meta-tags, meta

I got an error message from Google webmaster where it asked me to change the duplicate meta tags of different pages to enhance user experience. The list of pages includes those pages whose meta tags can't be accessed/edited from backend, like Contact Us, Track your order, Orders and returns, Sign Up, etc. All these page pages have same meta as the page has. I'd just like to know how can I change them? I'm serious about it because Google suggested me to amend these pages.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the meta information for each and every page in Magento if you are a developer then you can add few lines of code in local.xml for each and every page.

For example for contact us page you can add the following lines

```
<contacts_index_index>
     <reference name="head">
      <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="contacts"><title>META TITLE HERE</title></action>
      <action method="setDescription" translate="description" module="contacts"><description>META DESCRIPTION HERE</description></action>
      <action method="setKeywords" translate="keywords" module="contacts"><keywords>META KEYWORDS HERE</keywords></action>
</reference>
</contacts_index_index>
```

or for login page you can add the following lines

```
<customer_account_login>
   <reference name="head">
    <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="contacts"><title>META TITLE HERE</title></action>
    <action method="setDescription" translate="description" module="contacts"><description>META DESCRIPTION HERE</description></action>
    <action method="setKeywords" translate="keywords" module="contacts"><keywords>META KEYWORDS HERE</keywords></action>
   </reference>
 </customer_account_login>
```

But if you are not a developer then you can use the following module which allows you to change code of each and every page without writing a single line of code.

http://www.scommerce-mage.co.uk/magento-meta-information-for-any-page.html

Hope the above information helps.

Cheers
S